# Custom color options in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, colors

I am developing wordpress theme. I need, that user could set in admin panel some color(with color picker), and this color can be used in my template.

How to realize it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you read this tutorial to learn how to create a settings page, this tutorial give you a good start point

http://ottopress.com/2009/wordpress-settings-api-tutorial/

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have already figured out with this problem and making settings page with option tree plugin.